# Ansible copy module: Which is the default local relative directory?

Tags: directory, ansible, copy

The Ansible project has this directory structure:

```
roles/
  common/
    tasks/
       main.yml
group_vars/
  group1.yml
  group2.yml
inventory/
  hosts
```

When using the [copy module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html) inside the `main.yml` like this:

```
- name: Copy test directory
  copy:
    src: ./test
    dest: /tmp
    mode: 0600
    owner: user
    group: user
```

Where is Ansible going to look for the test directory?
I can not find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

> Q: *"Where is Ansible going to look for the test directory?"*

A: Quoting from [The magic of ‘local’ paths](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbook_pathing.html#the-magic-of-local-paths):

> ... relative paths get attempted first with a **files|templates|vars** appended (if not already present), **depending on the action being taken, ‘files’ is the default. (i.e include_vars will use vars/)**. The paths will be searched from most specific to the most general (i.e role before play). dependent roles WILL be traversed (i.e task is in role2, role2 is a dependency of role1, role2 will be looked at first, then role1,then play). i.e

```
role search path is rolename/{files|vars|templates}/, rolename/tasks/.
play search path is playdir/{files|vars|templates}/, playdir/.
```